# How to use a fixed validation set (not K-fold cross validation) in Scikit-learn for a decision tree classifier/random forest classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am new to machine learning and data science. Sorry, if it is a very stupid question.

I see there is an inbuilt function for cross-validation but not for a fixed validation set. I have a dataset with 50,000 samples labeled with years from 1990 to 2010. I need to train different classifiers on 1990-2008 samples, then validate on 2009 samples, and test on 2010 samples.

EDIT:
After @Quan Tran's answer, I tried this. This is how it should be?

```
# Fit a decision tree
estimator1 = DecisionTreeClassifier( max_depth = 9, max_leaf_nodes=9)
estimator1.fit(X_train, y_train)
print estimator1


# validate using validation set
acc = np.zeros((20,20))  # store accuracy 
for i in range(20):
     for j in range(20):
         estimator1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = i+1, max_leaf_nodes=j+2)
         estimator1.fit(X_valid, y_valid)
         y_pred = estimator1.predict(X_valid)
         acc[i,j] = accuracy_score(y_valid, y_pred)

best_mod = np.where(acc == acc.max())
print best_mod
print acc[best_mod]



 # Predict target values
estimator1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = int(best_mod[0]) + 1, max_leaf_nodes= int(best_mod[1]) + 2)
estimator1.fit(X_valid, y_valid)
y_pred = estimator1.predict(X_test)
confusion = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

TP = confusion[1, 1]
TN = confusion[0, 0]
FP = confusion[0, 1]
FN = confusion[1, 0]


# Classification Accuracy
print "======= ACCURACY ========"
print((TP + TN) / float(TP + TN + FP + FN))
print accuracy_score(y_valid, y_pred)
# store the predicted probabilities for class 
y_pred_prob = estimator1.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]


# plot a ROC curve for y_test and y_pred_prob
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_prob)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.title('ROC curve for DecisionTreeClassifier')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate (1 - Specificity)')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate (Sensitivity)')
plt.grid(True)

print("======= AUC ========")
print(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_prob))
```

I get this answer, which is **not the best accuracy**.

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=9,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=9, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')
(array([5]), array([19]))
[ 0.8489011]
======= ACCURACY ========
0.574175824176
0.538461538462
======= AUC ========
0.547632099893
```

Comment: I don't think I got what you meant by saying "I need to train different classifiers on 1990-2008 samples, then validate on 2009 samples, and test on 2010 samples."

Comment: @MMF I have a weather data with 50,000 samples approx of one city. The questions are (1) "Train a random forest. Train on 1990-2008. Use 2009 as a validation set. 2010 should be your test set." (2)  "Train a single decision tree. Train on 1990-2008. Use 2009 as a validation set. 2010 should be your test set." All using Scikit-learn.

Comment: You mean '2009' as the set of all samples labeled as '2009' right ?

Comment: Cross validation and train_test_split split the data randomly. The split you want to do is not random. What you want to do is filter your data into three data sets, using python or any library such as pandas, *before* you feed them to the classifiers.

Comment: @MMF Yes. You are right. sorry. I am new to this subject. Data columns are Year, Month, Day, Max Temperature, Min Temp, Max Humidity, Min Humidity, Rain, etc.

Comment: What are your classes ? Predict the season ?

Comment: Predict Rain on next day. Train a single decision tree to predict the question of will it rains tomorrow? (binary classification: if it rained tomorrow (1) or not (0))

Comment: Edit your post and show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, there are three separate sets. The train set, the test set and the validation set.

The **train set** is used to fit the parameters of the classifier. For example:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
clf.fit(trainfeatures, labels)
```

The **validation set** is used to tune the hyper parameters of the classifier or find the cutoff point for the training procedure. For example, in the case of Decision tree, max_depth is a hyper parameter. You will need to find a good set of hyper parameters by experimenting with different values of hyper parameters (tuning) and compare the performance measures (accuracy/precision,..) on the validation set.

The **test set** is used to estimate the error rate on unseen data. After having the performance measures on the test set, the model must not be trained/tuned any further.

Comment: Great. I get better understanding now. Does that mean I should be using Accuracy or AUC or MSE on the validation set to find a good set of hyperparameters?

Comment: Yes, that should be it.

Comment: I edited the question. Please let me know if you find any errors. I, though, found low accuracy even after choosing best parameters.